# Python Pandas Groupby add column divide to get average

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a large dataset (15k+ rows) and I am trying to show the proportional share of investment based on number of investors(not actual ownership).  This is a known glitch, but we are trying to solve for representation.  I can currently remove duplicates within SQL(if i have 3 customers with investment of 600, i would then remove duplicates to have 1 customer with 600, but it is all or nothing and instead I would like to show these three customers with 200 each).

I need the groupby function to take into consideration Customerid, parentid, and amount of investment. Then i need to create another column and give the avg investment per customer (Investment/#customers for that particular dollar amount for that customer id/parent id combination) per each sponsorname/row.  And finally, i need to groupby, sum the investment by SponsorName and do a count of customer id.

Dataset:

```
CustomerID   ParentID    SponsorName    Investment
1            55          Bob            600
1            55          Jack           600
1            55          Mary           600
5            65          Bill           1200
5            65          Jim            1200
5            65          Jill           1200
1            55          Bob            1000
1            55          Jack           1000
1            55          Mary           1000
```

Output:

```
CustomerID   ParentID    SponsorName    Investment   Avg Investment
1            55          Bob            600          200
1            55          Jack           600          200
1            55          Mary           600          200
5            65          Bill           1200         400
5            65          Jim            1200         400
5            65          Jill           1200         400
1            55          Bob            1000         333.33
1            55          Jack           1000         333.33
1            55          Mary           1000         333.33
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `GroupBy` + `transform` with `size`:

```
counts = df.groupby(['CustomerID', 'ParentID'])['SponsorName'].transform('size')
df['Avg Investment'] = df['Investment'] / counts
```

Output:

```
   CustomerID  ParentID SponsorName  Investment  Avg Investment
0           1        55         Bob         600           200.0
1           1        55        Jack         600           200.0
2           1        55        Mary         600           200.0
3           5        65        Bill        1200           400.0
4           5        65         Jim        1200           400.0
5           5        65        Jill        1200           400.0
```

**Updated for your revised question, courtesy @ScottBoston**

```
group_keys = ['CustomerID', 'ParentID', 'Investment']
counts = df.groupby(group_keys)['SponsorName'].transform('size')
df['Avg Investment'] = df['Investment'] / counts
```

Output:

```
   CustomerID  ParentID SponsorName  Investment  Avg Investment
0           1        55         Bob         600      200.000000
1           1        55        Jack         600      200.000000
2           1        55        Mary         600      200.000000
3           5        65        Bill        1200      400.000000
4           5        65         Jim        1200      400.000000
5           5        65        Jill        1200      400.000000
6           1        55         Bob        1000      333.333333
7           1        55        Jack        1000      333.333333
8           1        55        Mary        1000      333.333333
```

Comment: I like yours better (-:

Comment: Thank you so much, this puts us very close, but i am running into a snag, i am going to edit the post.  When there are more iterations of the same customerid/parentid with a different set investment, the denominator grows, where if possible i would just like to divide by each individual set.  I apologize as i did not include this in the original post.  I noticed after your post that there are many cross groupings of investors, which added complexity to the query.

Comment: GENIUS!!!  Thank you all so much!  Just out of curiosity, why was it necessary to update the groupby statement to include a variable representing the 3 elements?  Before i edited, i attempted to add in Investment, but i did not see any change.  Is there a limit of 2 within the groupby statement?  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @John, There's no limit. But it's clearer when you limit the length of your lines of code, e.g. PEP8 has an 80-character limit recommended. Maintain a longer list separately is also cleaner.

Comment: @jpp - thank you for your help!  That makes perfect sense!